# Which Python version should I download to run tensorflow GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

I try to set my CUDA Tensorflow on my windows 10.

I would like to know what is the newest version of Python that works without bugs with the CUDA tensorflow and in which version.

Also what version of cuDNN should i use?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: I found the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source)

---

It is not very well documented, I agree with you.

```
Tensorflow v2.0 alpha release
Cuda v10.0
Cudnn v7.4.2
Python 3.6+
```

Read more [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6235)

Answer (score 0):

you can use any 
but it's better to use python version 3 with pip install 19.0 version 
as for the Cuda version you need to check what cuda version can be rub for your GPU 
and for cuDnn it will be desided on your cuda version